# using ARR with port change

Tags: windows, azure, arr

So I have what I thought was a simple need... I want to take URL's for a domain... something like myapp.somedomain.com and forward it to a web farm (two web servers) sitting behind an ARR proxy. Simple enough if everything is running on port 80. But if I want to say route all the requests to the web farm on port 8080 instead.. well, I'm missing something.

I have the farm define, I have load balancing configured for weighted round robin. I also have a URL rewrite rule that properly detects the domain in question and can forwards to the 'default' port of 80 on the web far. And despite adding the port to the rewrite URI, I can't get it to go to the proper port.

Any tips for the missing piece to this puzzle?

PS - entire "farm" is running in Windows Azure, but that shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: Create a simple Worker Role Project. Install the Session Affinity plugin (https://github.com/richorama/AzurePluginLibrary/tree/master/plugins/SessionAffinity4), RDP to any of the workers and check the configuration. I just can't do it right now. It makes successfull ARR configuration from 80 (input endpoint) to 8080 (internal Endpoint). More on the plugin: http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/07/sessionaffinity-plugin-for-windows-azure.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create the farm you will specify the host\address; below click on advanced and change the ports to the desired destination ports.